# How to create enumerated directories in subdirectories in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I want to create a folder in each subfolder with a number in it's name.

Lets say I have a following folder structure in my root folder:

```
\sub1\
\sub2\
\sub3\
```

after I've ran the command it should look like this:

```
\sub1\fold1
\sub2\fold2
\sub3\fold3
```

I'm new to all of this terminal stuff so i could only come up with how to create a folder in each subdirectory:

```
ls -directory | % {md ($_.name + '\FolderName')}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following your desired output, `\sub3\fold3`, is `fold3` named like that because it's parent directory ends with `3` or because it was the iteration number `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want sequence numbers starting with `1`, irrespective of the name of the parent directory:

```
$i=1
ls -directory | % { md (Join-Path $_.FullName "Folder$(($i++))") }
```

To instead incorporate the number embedded in the parent directory name:

```
ls -directory | % { md (Join-Path $_.FullName "Folder$($_.Name -replace '\D')") }
```